# Can'not launch django installed inside docker

Tags: django, docker, virtualenv

I am using Docker to launch my app which imports django. I want to do it inside my git repository.
My Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /configurator

CMD virtualenv -p python3.8 venv
CMD . venv/bin/activate
CMD pip install -U setuptools pip
CMD pip install django

COPY . /configurator/

CMD cd cconfigurator/

ENTRYPOINT /configurator/cconfigurator/manage.py runserver 8000
```

And I see an error:

```
docker run configurator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/configurator/cconfigurator/manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/configurator/cconfigurator/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/configurator/cconfigurator/manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you change your CMD's to RUN?

Comment: docker build -t configurator .
```Sending build context to Docker daemon  622.6kB
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3
 ---> d47898c6f4b0
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /configurator
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31fd5d81aa7a
Step 3/9 : RUN virtualenv -p python3.8 venv
 ---> Running in 4298204f4a38
/bin/sh: 1: virtualenv: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c virtualenv -p python3.8 venv' returned a non-zero code: 127```
I get an another error

Comment: @dfundako I added `RUN pip install virtualenv` but still have problems...
```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenv
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install virtualenv' returned a non-zero code: 1```

Comment: Why do you need a virtualenv in the container?

Comment: @dfundako I commented these part of code. Probably, I have problems with accessing the net via Docker container but I don't know how to solve them(

Comment: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-virtualenv-dockerfile/